# Hex strokeStyle fails for dashed lines

Tags: html, canvas, stroke

I have the following function (compiled via babel)

```
const DASH_COLOUR = "x0FA9D8";
const DASH_DASH = 5;
const DASH_EMPTY = 5;
```

...

```
diagonalDraw(context, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
    context.save();
    console.log(DASH_COLOUR);
    context.strokeStyle = DASH_COLOUR;
    context.setLineDash([DASH_DASH, DASH_EMPTY]);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
    context.lineTo(toX, toY);
    console.log("readBack", context.strokeStyle)
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
```

The console output is:

```
x0FA9D8
readBack 0
```

The FireFox eyedropper says the line is various shades of grey (RGB all equal).

Is not getting the same value back really a violation of the spec?
Why doesn't it work?

Note: if DASH_COLOUR = "blue" it does work.

Comment: prefix color with hash

Comment: Could you make that an answer?  I can't see straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the color property to correct hex format:

```
  const DASH_COLOUR = "#0FA9D8";
```